# Dojo: How to get an element of an element variable

Tags: javascript, dojo

For example, ideally I'd like to go:

```
newelement = myElement.query('whatever');
```

Basically how mootools does this:

```
element = oldemement.getElement('whatever');
```

What the equivalent in dojo? If it makes a different, I am using this in a drag and drop creator function:

```
function myCreator( item, hint ) {
    console.log(item);
    var a = dojo.query('.name', item)
    console.log(a);
   var myDiv = dojo.create( 'table', { innerHTML: item.name });
   if (hint == 'avatar') myDiv.innerHTML = 'Im an avator of ' + item.name;
   return {node: myDiv, data: item, type: item.type};
}
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
    new dojo.dnd.Source("categoryTable", {creator: myCreator });
...
```

Log of item returns:

```
 <td><span class="dojoDndHandle">::</span></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="category_8" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="category_8" id="category_8" value="1"></td>
<td class="name"><a href="/news/admin/editCategory/8">Category A</a></td>
 <td><span title="18:57:11 04/07/2010">3 days ago</span><br>By <a href="/user/1/">Ashley</a></td>
```

1 day ago
By [Ashley](/user/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
dojo.query('whatever', oldelement)
```

See [dojo.query()](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/query.html#dojo-query)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my dnd creator function, see edited question for more

Comment: the second arg to dojo.query is supposed to be an element, it doesn't look like that's what `item` refers to (what is `item`?). also note that dojo.query returns a node list.